# Angular: MissingServletRequestParameterException when sending POST request with required parameters

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

When making a POST request in Angular, I am encountering a "MissingServletRequestParameterException" error. The error message states that the required request parameter 'email' is not present. However, when I test the API using Postman and provide the email and password parameters in the URL, the request is successful and returns the expected result.

I have implemented the login functionality using Angular's HttpClient module and a login service. The code seems correct, but I'm unsure why the required parameters are not being included in the request when using Angular.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Here is link of api : http://localhost:55624/doctors/login?email=test@gmail.com&password=1234
return :

```
{
    "message": "Login successful",
    "resultat": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "H",
        "lastName": "H",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "etat": "ok"
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public Map<String, Object> loginDoctor(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        Doctor doctor = doctorRepository.findByEmail(email);
        
        if (doctor != null && doctor.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            
            return Response.success("Login successful", doctor);
        } else {
            
            return Response.failure("Invalid email or password", null);
        }
    }
```

Angular :

```
//service
export class LoginService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:55624/doctors/login';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const body = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body);
  }
}
//component 
export class LoginComponent { 
  email!: string;
  password!: string;
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  login(): void {
    this.loginService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(
      response => {
        // Traitement de la réponse de l'API en cas de succès
        console.log('Login successful:', response);
      },
      error => {
        // Traitement de l'erreur en cas d'échec de l'API
        console.error('Login failed:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I have verified that the email and password values are correctly bound to the component properties and are available when the login method is called. I have also confirmed that the API works as expected when tested with Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering seems to be related to how you're sending the POST request from Angular. By default, Angular's `HttpClient.post()` method sends the request with a JSON payload in the request body, rather than as URL parameters. However, your server-side code expects the email and password parameters to be sent as URL parameters.

To resolve this issue, you need to update your Angular code to send the email and password as URL parameters instead of in the request body.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Update the `login()` method in your LoginService.